# Le parfum se hume OU le parfum s’hume ?

Tags: élision, pronoms-réfléchis

Dans le verbe *humer*, doit-on considérer le *h* comme muet ou aspiré ?

Et dans ce cas, dans la phrase suivante :

> Le parfum *σ* hume

Où *σ* représente le pronom réfléchis de la 3e personne *se*, doit-on le décliner sous la forme *se* ou bien l’élider sous la forme *s’* ?

En un mot, comme le résume le titre, doit on dire « le parfum **se** hume » ou « le parfum **s’** hume » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

« Humer » est un verbe dont le h est aspiré ([aidenet](http://www.aidenet.eu/grammaire01ac.htm)). Donc, il faut utiliser « se ».

> ([Bescherelle](https://bescherelle.ca/elision-devant-h-muet/)) D’autres h sont dits « aspirés », c’est-à-dire qu’ils bloquent l’élision. Ils empêchent les pronoms **je, le, la, me, te, se** de prendre une apostrophe.

[image]

Cet ngram semble montrer un usage très minoritaire de « s'hume », mais en fait cet usage n'existe pas : toutes les occurrences sont des faux positifs, comme on peut le vérifier à partir des   [pages d'exemples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22s%27hume%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).